# ActionScript 3.0 Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, null

For my first project in flash I decided to make a little football game. It was working whenever I was identifying each individual object but then since I wanted to add more little AI players, I tried to make the movement work with some Arrays containing the objects but then it returned this error message. Any help?

```
function movers(event:Event):void
{
  for (var qwerty:int=0;qwerty<=(ALIEN.length);qwerty++) {
    var run:Object=ALIEN[qwerty];
    run.rotation=Math.atan2(bc.y-run.y,bc.x-run.x)/(Math.PI/180);
    run.x+=Math.cos(sym.rotation*Math.PI/180)*SPD;
    run.y+=Math.sin(sym.rotation*Math.PI/180)*SPD;
  }

  if (ftblFLY) {
    ftbl.x+=Math.cos(ftbl.rotation*Math.PI/180)*7;
    ftbl.y+=Math.sin(ftbl.rotation*Math.PI/180)*7;
  }

  for (var wer:int=0;wer<=(team.length);wer++) {
    if (ftbl.hitTestObject(wer)) {
      if (wer!=bc) {
        bc=wer;
        ftblFLY=false;
      }
    }
  }

  if (bc!=wr) {
    wr.x+=Math.cos(wr.rotation*Math.PI/180)*SPD;
    wr.y+=Math.sin(wr.rotation*Math.PI/180)*SPD;
  }

  for (var asdf:int=0;qwerty<=(ALIEN.length);asdf++) {
    var runner:Object=ALIEN[asdf];
    if (runner.hitTestObject(bc)) {
      stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movers);
      stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyers);
      stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicko);
      texter.text="Tackled!!!";
    }
  }

  bc.x+=Math.cos(bc.rotation*Math.PI/180)*(SPD*playaRD);
  bc.y+=Math.sin(bc.rotation*Math.PI/180)*(SPD*playaRD);
  bc.rotation=bc.rotation+(turno*playaTD);

  ftbl.rotation=bc.rotation;
  ftbl.x=bc.x;
  ftbl.y=bc.y;

  if (bc.y<=0) {
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movers);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyers);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicko);
    texter.text="Touchdown!!!";
  }
}
```

Comment: You should go into the fla publish settings and click the check box to enable debugging.  That way, when you get an error message it will point directly to the line number on which the error happened.  Because this all looks like timeline code, and many of these objects *could* be movieclips or buttons on the stage, just a simple code examination may or may not turn up what's null... it could be that you're trying to reference a clip that isn't in existence at the time (no matter if you *think* it is).  So get the specific line number and if it's still not clear, come back and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be `< ALIEN.length` not <= same with wer

something like this:

```
for (var qwerty:int=0;qwerty<(ALIEN.length);qwerty++) {

for (var wer:int=0;wer<(team.length);wer++) {

for (var asdf:int=0;qwerty<(ALIEN.length);asdf++) {
```

lets say you have an array x of 10 objects then your

**x.length is 10** 
but your array will start at 0 so you will have values from 
**x[0] to x[9]** 
therefore, if you do: 
**for (var i:int=0;i<=(x.length);i++) {** 
you wont get a value for x[10] and it so you get a null object reference error.

Comment: thanks that helps, yet for some reason it still returns that error

Comment: @SD5 then there is another bug, most likely with one of the other object variables you're using. start commenting out sections of the function and determine which specific portion of the code is throwing the bug. Let me know what you find.

Comment: This should make your life easier - a little known trick in the Flash IDE is that you can set it up to give you line numbers for runtime errors, so you don't have to comment out code until you find what you're looking for. Here's a blog post I wrote on the subject: http://mykola.bilokonsky.net/2010/08/get-line-numbers-on-runtime-errors-in-flash/

Comment: I found the problem, it was an error where whenever I was trying to use arrays for it I forgot to change the part where it says (wer!=bc) because I forgot to change it to an object value. Thanks all of yall and @Myk that's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Your coding conventions make your code difficult to understand...

Did you initialize your ALIEN[] array outside of your function, or your for loop? If you didn't, Flash will throw the error you're seeing. You can't use a variable until you initialize it.

If you haven't, you can either use

```
var ALIEN:Array = new Array();
```

or

```
var ALIEN:Array = [];
```

As you progress, you may want to look into Vectors, which offer some advantages in iteration.

Good luck!

Comment: Use the second. Less overhead and creates the same thing. Its documented as the best method to instantiate an array

Comment: @Glycerine, do you know if that's also the case for Vectors and other objects? I have always preferred the "new" keyword (as C++ was my first real language) as I like the idea of calling the object constructor, but many sources say that "[]" is much faster. If this is true for all object containers (arrays, vectors, dictionaries, objects), however, I'll begin to use it and just get used to the syntax.

_Edit: I just answered my own question using Flash Builder - it doesn't. "[]" is strictly an array type, and does not work for vectors or dictionaries._

Comment: I don't think a Vector object has a shorthand* _citation needed_ yet - but array [], and an object {} - should work with Flash builder. I would check but my flash is being silly today. I certainly read in the documentation `new Array()` and `new Object()` is unrequired and creates more harm than good. I concur with your statement of you prefer it though.

Comment: @Glycerine You're correct - objects take {}, but Vectors and Dictionaries don't (Flash Builder complained). Good catch! Truthfully, I rarely use Arrays and Objects, but when I do, I'll be sure to use the shorthand notation.